# Error NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null. Receiver: null Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

El error es el siguiente:

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic))
```

Estoy consultando un servidor de LDAP, a través de  un servicio rest, para poder mapear los datos lo hice de la siguiente manera en mi servicio:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<RespuestaLdap> respuestaLdapFromJson(String str) => List<RespuestaLdap>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => RespuestaLdap.fromJson(x)));

String respuestaLdapToJson(List<RespuestaLdap> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class RespuestaLdap {
    RespuestaLdap({
        this.path,
        this.properties,
    });

    String path;
    Properties properties;

    factory RespuestaLdap.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RespuestaLdap(
        path: json["path"],
        properties: Properties.fromJson(json["properties"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "path": path,
        "properties": properties.toJson(),
    };
}

class Properties {
    Properties({
        this.cn,
        this.department,
        this.adspath,
        this.employeenumber,
    });

    List<String> cn;
    List<String> department;
    List<String> adspath;
    List<String> employeenumber;

    factory Properties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Properties(
        cn: List<String>.from(json["cn"].map((x) => x)),
        department: List<String>.from(json["department"].map((x) => x)),
        adspath: List<String>.from(json["adspath"].map((x) => x)),
        employeenumber: List<String>.from(json["employeenumber"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cn": List<dynamic>.from(cn.map((x) => x)),
        "department": List<dynamic>.from(department.map((x) => x)),
        "adspath": List<dynamic>.from(adspath.map((x) => x)),
        "employeenumber": List<dynamic>.from(employeenumber.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

A lo cual mi respuesta es la siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "path": "LDAP://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/CN=XXXXXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=XX,DC=XX",
        "properties": {
            "cn": [
                "USUARIO NOMBRE"
            ],
            "department": [
                "DEPARTAMENTO USUARIO"
            ],
            "adspath": [
                "LDAP://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/CN=USUARIO NOMBRE,OU=DEPARTAMENTO USUARIO,DC=XXXXXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX"
            ],
            "employeenumber": [
                "NUMERO TRABAJADOR "
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Hasta aquí no hay problema, porque si puedo mapear los datos, el verdadero problema sucede cuando mi respuesta viene sin numero de trabajador y departamento ya que mi respuesta viene de la siguiente manera:

```
[
    {
        "path": "LDAP://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/CN=XXXXXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=XX,DC=XX",
        "properties": {            
            "adspath": [
                "LDAP://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/CN=USUARIO NOMBRE,OU=DEPARTAMENTO USUARIO,DC=XXXXXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX"
            ],
        "cn": [
                "USUARIO NOMBRE"
            ],
        }
    }
]
```

Al no traer las propiedades me genera el error antes mencionado, investigando un poco lo que hice fue modificar en donde se mapea los datos asi :

```
class Properties {
  Properties({
    this.employeenumber,
    this.department,
    required this.cn,
    required this.adspath,
  });

  List<String>? employeenumber;
  List<String>? department;
  List<String> cn;
  List<String> adspath;

  factory Properties.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Properties(
        employeenumber: List<String>.from(json["employeenumber"].map((x) => x)),
        department: List<String>.from(json["department"].map((x) => x)),
        cn: List<String>.from(json["cn"].map((x) => x)),
        adspath: List<String>.from(json["adspath"].map((x) => x)),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "employeenumber": List<dynamic>.from(employeenumber!.map((x) => x)),
        "department": List<dynamic>.from(department!.map((x) => x)),
        "cn": List<dynamic>.from(cn.map((x) => x)),
        "adspath": List<dynamic>.from(adspath.map((x) => x)),
      };
}

NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic))
```

y no se como solucionarlo, agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: me parece que tu error recae en que la respuesta viene dentro de una lista osea un array y el metodo map es para recorrer un json podrias 'parsear' la respuesta antes de llamar al metodo map algo asi como = respuesta[0] . con tal de obtener el un resputa apta para la utilizacion del metodo

Comment: Que podría hacer para solucionar el problema